# How to proper delete plugin in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am working with WordPress plugin **wp-latest-posts** I deactivated this

plugin then deleted this plugin using FTP.After that I again upload fresh same

plugin but it's configuration setting has a previous value which I was added like

css etc. I checked database but this plugin is not generating any table where it

stores the css data and why previous data is coming fresh plguin setting.

Answer (score 1):

Normally good plugins always provide options to uninstall them completely(files and their database modifications) from the admin panel itself.

First of all please note that "It is a good practice to delete plugins from WordPress admin in spite of deleting their files from FTP".

Now for a case when you delete a plugin from WordPress admin and still it automatically fill your previous settings as before on their next install. It means that this plugin is not coded well.

So we need to check below mentioned things:

1. Sometimes plugin create tables in database at the time of their installation, so check for them and delete them.
2. Some plugin save their values in "wp_options" table in WordPress database. First check manually for them and then try few plugins that help you in doing this like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugins-garbage-collector and https://wordpress.org/plugins/clean-options
3. Some plugins create few files or folders generally in "wp-content" directory. Check for them.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because some plugins store data in the wp_options table in your database, the correct way to uninstall a Plugin, is doing it from the WordPress Plugin Tab:

1.- Go To WordPress Dashboard
2.- Click on Plugins > Installed Plugins
3.- Select the Plugin that you want to delete and click on deactivate (if it's activated)
4.- Then click Delete

That way even the data that the plugin saves in the wp_options will be removed. Otherwise if you want to delete that data manually, you will need to have MySql Knowledge to find the data in that database.